# What is the relation between LTRB and Offset?

Tags: flutter

I need to check whether the given set of points (in Offset) is present inside a Rect (as LTRB). 
Also I do not have clarity over how to draw a Rect using fromLTRB(). The documentation says:

```
(double left, double top, double right, double bottom) → Rect

Construct a rectangle from its left, top, right, and bottom edges.
```

Does the four parameters represent the lengths of the four sides? If so how is the position in the screen determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I) `fromLTRB` stands for from Left, Top, Right and Bottom.
Suppose you draw a `Rect` using `fromLTRB` as shown.

`Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 30, 50)`

then the rectangle is contruction as the following steps.
1. Left and Top ends of the enclosing widgets act as the Left and Top margins
2. The first parameter is the distance of the Left side of the `Rect` from Left margin.
3. The second parameter is the distance of the Top side of the `Rect` from Top margin.
4. The third parameter is the distance of the Right side of the `Rect` from Left margin.
5. The forth parameter is the distance of the Bottom side of the `Rect` from Top margin.

Hence for the given example rectangle would be constructed with sides of lengths: (50 - 0) and (30 - 0)

II) `Offset` parameter returns coordinate of the point taking Left and Bottom end of the screen as the two margins.